# (Spring Integration) How to handle Messages with Reactive consumer?

Tags: spring-integration, project-reactor

I am using Spring Integration 5.1 with Java DSL and Project Reactor.

How can I handle Messages at last step of `IntegrationFlow` processing pipeline with

```
interface RemoteApiClient {
  fun consumeMessage(payload: Payload): Mono<Void>
}
```

?

I want my messages to be consumed **sequentially**, next one is consumed only after previous `Mono` completes sucesfully or with **error**. And I want to recover from cases when inbound pipeline fails with exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please, elaborate more about the `to recover from cases when inbound pipeline fails with exception` case, but for first your question it could be `Mono` API like this:

```java
    /**
     * Join the termination signals from this mono and another source into the returned
     * void mono
     *
     * <p>
     * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/and.svg" alt="">
     * <p>
     * @param other the {@link Publisher} to wait for
     * complete
     * @return a new combined Mono
     * @see #when
     */
    public final Mono<Void> and(Publisher<?> other) {
```

or:

```java
    /**
     * Let this {@link Mono} complete then play another Mono.
     * <p>
     * In other words ignore element from this {@link Mono} and transform its completion signal into the
     * emission and completion signal of a provided {@code Mono<V>}. Error signal is
     * replayed in the resulting {@code Mono<V>}.
     *
     * <p>
     * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/thenWithMonoForMono.svg" alt="">
     *
     * @reactor.discard This operator discards the element from the source.
     *
     * @param other a {@link Mono} to emit from after termination
     * @param <V> the element type of the supplied Mono
     *
     * @return a new {@link Mono} that emits from the supplied {@link Mono}
     */
    public final <V> Mono<V> then(Mono<V> other) {
```